# Formspree form not working on custom designed contact form

Tags: html, forms, css, contact-form

I am hosting a site on github i.e. githubpages.AS It is a static site I used **`Formspree`** for my contact form but unfortunately it is not working with custom designed Contact form (with required parameters put in specified fields).
But finally the clicking of submit button does no action at all..
Here is the code I am implementing for the form.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="action="https://formspree.io/jmscb56@gmail.com" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm">
          <div class="row">

            <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
            <div id="errormessage"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="form-group contact-block1">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="6" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!--    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-defeault btn-send" value="Send"> -->
     <button type="submit" value="Send">Send</button>
            </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://ghac-2017.github.io/#contact" />

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated..As I cannot find what i felt short of..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually You cannot use `formspree` form as per your own customization , i.e. editing the basic (given/allotted) form values. It will work well when you use the given form values without your own customization , it will loose its functionality if you edit the basic layout of the given form by `formspree`.